# Gitlab can't trigger drone build

Tags: gitlab, drone.io

The drone page always shows this page

[image]

even if I have added the `.drone.yml` file.

By the way, the token set in gitlab is the `api key` in drone user page?
And the `Drone url` in gitlab is the drone root url or project url?
[image]

*Update: The webhook in gitlab seems not working.[image]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost is not a valid URL you can give to gitlab.
It is a local reference to your own machine. You need to setup your drone install somewhere it can be accessed from outside your local network, using a domain or at least a public IP.

You can try with your router IP and to do in your router some port redirection of external port 3333 to your machine's 3333.

Edit : I assumed you were using a hosted version of gitlab. If you are using a self-hosted version, make sure that you use the IP of your drone server. Using localhost is only possible if the drone server is the same as the Gitlab server.

Comment: Oh~ I realized this problem suddenly.